# how does the tempid number relate to the final :tempid hashmap?

Tags: clojure, datomic

If I want to stick a record into datomic:

i.e.

```
{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user -1226692165], :address/country "Australia"}
```

I get a map back:

```
{:db-before #db{1000 #inst "2014-10-28T05:39:40.413-00:00"},
 :db-after #db{1001 #inst "2014-10-28T05:39:53.626-00:00"},
 :tx-data [#datom[13194139534313 50 #inst "2014-10-28T05:39:53.626-00:00" 13194139534313 true]
           #datom[17592186045418 67 "Australia" 13194139534313 true]],
 :tempids {-9223350047848912453 17592186045418}}
```

with -9223350047848912453 being the key for the tempid

now.... how do these map to each other?

```
 #db/id[:db.part/user -1226692165] <=> -9223350047848912453
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map the temporary ids to entity ids using the [resolve-tempid](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/resolve-tempid) function.

Something along these lines:

```
(defn transact!
  [conn tx]
  (let [{eids :tempids} @(d/transact conn tx)]
        (map #(d/resolve-tempid (d/db conn)
                                eids
                                (:db/id %)) tx)))
```

The relationship otherwise is an ordered one (first with first, second with second, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

They don't. It is undefined behavior.

http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/tempid:

> Values of n from -1 to -1000000, inclusive, are reserved for
>   user-created tempids.

(Your tempid is too small.)

Comment: So what's the point of having a tempid map if it can't be mapped back to the original tempids?

Comment: It can, but not in this case, because your tempid is invalid in the first place.

Comment: What does it mean by user created tempid? I thought that was what I was doing

Comment: Yes, but the one you specified is out of range (lower than -1000000).